# url-pattern /* serves jsp files and static assets as seperate requests

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web.xml, url-pattern

I have a simple servlet which renders different content based on different geo locations
for example:

```
example.com/us
example.com/de
example.com/uk
example.com/..
```

so actually the servlet should supports all geo locations as url-pattern. So thats why I defined the rule below in my `web.xml` file:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

this is how the servlet look like:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{
  String showPage = "/pages/show.jsp";
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    System.out.println("servlet initiated... ~> "+request.getRequestURI());
    ...
    request.getRequestDispatcher(showPage).forward(request, response);

  }

}
```

As soon as I try to forward the page, the servlet starts again and again; it tries to also handle the request `/page/show.jsp`.
So I get such an ouput when I try to access `example.com/us`:

```
servlet initiated... ~> /us
servlet initiated... ~> /page/show.jsp
Exception...
servlet initiated... ~> /page/show.jsp
Exception...
servlet initiated... ~> /page/show.jsp
...
```

It throws an exception because my servlet is not expecting such a url-pattern `/page/show.jsp` but it triggers because I have define `/*` url-pattern in my web.xml file.

Any idea? how can I skip or exclude the unwanted requests like the one above? Thanks.

Comment: what is your exception ?

Comment: @erencan: the exception complains about the `/page/show.jsp` request. So after `/us` I want the servlet to stop and not process other requests like `/page/show.jsp`

Comment: Your question is not clear. You have already redirected the request to  `/pages/show.jsp` I think, you have not posted all the code, exactly the code which throws exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bart answer gave me the clue. Actually there are many ways to handle this, one is to use `Filters` and the other one is to define all the static routes in `web.xml` and instead of the `/*` I have used `/`.

So to resolve the issue I change the url-pattern as below:

```
<!-- static assets -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- my servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
  servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You also don't need to define the pattern for `org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet` its already there by default.
So After above changes everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a specific reference but I believe that "/*" root url pattern conflicts with the default mapping in the the global web.xml which could be contributing to your problem.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- The mapping for the default servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

try adding explicit jsp servlet tag and servlet mapping to avoid processing the jsp through the default mapping which is created with the "/" root url pattern.  I'm not sure that this will solve your problem.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>showpage</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/pages/show.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>showpage</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/show</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Another more explicit solution would be to create a url pattern that differentiates all of the country geo requests.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/geo/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So example.com/geo/us etc will map explicitly

I attempted the same global setting and had a similar problem where it recursively attempted the request and threw an exception over and over until I stopped the Tomcat server.  The problem was resolved when used more specific url pattern.

Answer (score 0):

When resolving pages/show.jsp the container will match on the longest path first then look at the file extension (.jsp) afterwards. So pages/show.jsp matches /* and therefore the container loads the Servlet again and doesn't initiate the JSP engine servlet.

Are all your jsps in a pages directory? Maybe you can add that mapping to your web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the servlet specification (2.5 here, but it should be the smae for newer version) :

> 1. The container will try to find an exact match of the path of the request to the
>      path of the servlet. A successful match selects the servlet.
> 2. The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix. This is done
>      by stepping down the path tree a directory at a time, using the ’/’ character as
>      a path separator. The longest match determines the servlet selected.
> 3. If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. .jsp), the servlet
>      container will try to match a servlet that handles requests for the extension.
>      An extension is defined as the part of the last segment after the last ’.’ character.
> 4. If neither of the previous three rules result in a servlet match, the container will
>      attempt to serve content appropriate for the resource requested. If a "default"
>      servlet is defined for the application, it will be used.

(source : [servlet-spec-2.5](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-2.5-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/))

So for your case, it should be sufficient to add a more precise mapping (as said by Si Kelly) :

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/show.jsp</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```